# Select UITableViewCell text when a new cell is added to a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a basic `UITableView` which contains basic `UITableViewCell`s. When I add a new cell to the table I'd like to:

1) scroll to the new row

2) select all of the text in the new UITableViewCell so that the keyboard becomes visible and the user can immediately edit the cell's text.

The next time through the event loop (after calling -reloadData on the table view) I do:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:wordIndex inSection:0];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPositionNone)];

UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
[cell.textLabel becomeFirstResponder];
cell.highlighted = YES;
```

The scrolling is correct but the text in the cell is not selected.

Comment: You can't edit the `UILabel` like that. You need to use `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in previous answer you can create custom child of UITableViewCell, add UITextField on that.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *editableTextField;
@end
```

Than you can catch didSelectRowAtIndexPath in your controller and set it's textfield to become first responder

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyTableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.editableTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

UPD: as a trouble resolve for Not-in-window-cell trouble, described by upper answer, you must call selectCellAtIndexPath in method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Answer (score 2):

A `UILabel` can't become a first responder because it returns `NO` from `canBecomeFirstResponder`.  To give the illusion of a label that is edited, you could try using a `UITextField` with a `borderStyle` of `UITextBorderStyleNone`.

Be careful with the timing of the `becomeFirstResponder` call, since a control can't be first responder if it is not a subview of a window.  This can happen if you are scrolling to a row that is very far off screen and immediately trying to call `becomeFirstResponder` before it is added as a visible row.

Comment: Thanks John. Do you mean that I have to create a custom UITableViewCell and add a UITextField to it?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make a custom cell, which is very easy to hook up in iOS 6.